# HBase Connection close()

Tags: hbase, connection-pooling

On each api call, I am doing this:

```
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Path hbase = new Path("hbase-site.xml");
        Path core = new Path("core-site.xml");
        config.addResource(hbase);
        config.addResource(core);
        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
```

And then closing this connection as soon as I get data for the current api call:

```
finally {
            if (null != connection) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Please tell me this model is correct or wrong. Each api request needs to be served this way or not -- opening the connection using ConnectionFactory, getting the data and finally closing it. I have heard people saying the connection need not be closed.

Please enlighten

Answer (score 3):

Usually, I pre-create `Connection` object and use it for multiple queries.
According to  [Hbase Reference Guide](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_api_as_of_hbase_1_0_0)

> In HBase 1.0, obtain a Connection object from ConnectionFactory and
>   thereafter, get from it instances of Table, Admin, and RegionLocator
>   on an as-need basis. When done, close the obtained instances. Finally,
>   be sure to cleanup your Connection instance before exiting.
>   Connections are heavyweight objects but thread-safe so you can create
>   one for your application and keep the instance around. Table, Admin
>   and RegionLocator instances are lightweight. Create as you go and then
>   let go as soon as you are done by closing them.